# Why no of primary shards can't be changed once index is created in Elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, distributed-computing

In Elasticsearch (ES), why can't we changed the no of primary shards once index is created, while we can change the no of replica shards anytime. I understand that changing replica shards is less overhead as compare to primary shards, but it doesn't seem to be a impossible task ?

Is there is any distributed system concept or performance gain for not allowing it ?

Comment: Are you seeking to increase the number of primary shards or decrease it?

Comment: @Val , Not atm but was curious why there is a restriction about it.

Comment: If you're seeking to decrease the number of shards you can use the [shrink index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-shrink-index.html), whereas if you're seeking to increase the number of shards you can use the [split index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-split-index.html). There are constraints in both APIs, but with careful planning in advance you can achieve both.

Comment: Also, for completeness' sake, the [Rollover Index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-rollover-index.html) can be used to increase/decrease the number of shards when an index meets certain conditions and a new one needs to be created.

Comment: @ElasticsearchNinja, I was seeking the same clarification for some time, did you had any inputs for the same . Is it always better to start with proper number of primary partitions first or start with small and scale it accordingly using splitting or shrinking ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was about to try to explain it myself, but I found out it's already properly explained in the official [Elasticsearch official guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/overallocation.html):

> Users often ask why Elasticsearch doesn’t support shard-splitting—the ability to split each shard into two or more pieces. The reason is that shard-splitting is a bad idea:
>
> - Splitting a shard is almost equivalent to reindexing your data. It’s a much heavier process than just copying a shard from one node to another.
> - Splitting is exponential. You start with one shard, then split into two, and then four, eight, sixteen, and so on. Splitting doesn’t allow you to increase capacity by just 50%.
> - Shard splitting requires you to have enough capacity to hold a second copy of your index. Usually, by the time you realize that you need to scale out, you don’t have enough free space left to perform the split.
>
> In a way, Elasticsearch does support shard splitting. You can always reindex your data to a new index with the appropriate number of shards (see Reindexing Your Data). It is still a more intensive process than moving shards around, and still requires enough free space to complete, but at least you can control the number of shards in the new index.